# Swagger @QueryParam cause error dropwizard

Tags: json, jackson, swagger, dropwizard

I added @QueryParam as part of my REST annotation but when I integrate with swagger it cause the following error when generation the swagger JSON:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:406)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.constructType(ObjectMapper.java:1187)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:62)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolveProperty(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:59)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:160)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:62)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolveProperty(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:59)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.converter.ModelConverters.readAsProperty(ModelConverters.java:71)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.DefaultParameterExtension.extractParameters(DefaultParameterExtension.java:49)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.SwaggerJersey2Jaxrs.extractParameters(SwaggerJersey2Jaxrs.java:100)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.getParameters(Reader.java:542)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.parseMethod(Reader.java:519)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:155)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:64)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:55)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setScan(BeanConfig.java:148)
```

Any one know how to resolve? Is it dependency errors?

I am using swagger com.wordnik swagger-jersey2-jaxrs version 1.5.1-M2. Any ideas?

Additional method detail

```
    @GET
    @Path("/stuff/test")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get some data", notes = "Returns some data", response = Existing.class, responseContainer = "List")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "some error message") })
    @Timed
    public Response getData(
            @ApiParam(value = "filter", required = false, name = "filter") @QueryParam("filter") Optional<String> filterParam)
            throws Exception {
//codes here
}
```

Comment: It would help if you add the method signature (including the annotations(.

Comment: @Ron I have added the method signature.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, can you try that without the `Optional`? Keep the String and see if it gives you the same error.

Comment: Yeah removing the Optional will cause it to run fine. But I want to keep the Optional.

Comment: It might be a generic issue because I am using Optional<String>.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I forgot to add the following mapping detail in the Application.run method:

`environment.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);`

Without this setting, the mapping of null values failed which may correspond to your Optional.

Comment: Tried that still fails with the same error message.

Comment: It might be a generic issue because I am using Optional<String>.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a regression in the migration from 1.3 to 1.5. We've had handling of `Optional` in the past but it probably slipped the conversion.

The best thing you can do right now about it is to open an issue on swagger-core.